# Tensorflow installation

Tags: tensorflow

Upon trying to install `Tensorflow` for `conda` environment, I encountered with the following error message, without any progress:

> tensorflow-1.1.0-cp35-cp35mwin_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read this [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and follow the guidelines there to refine your question with sufficient and specific information to describe your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried uninstalling and re-installing TensorFlow using pip within your Conda environment? I.e.:

```
pip uninstall tensorflow
```

Followed by:

```
 pip install tensorflow
```

If it doesn't work, the issue may be with your Python installation. TensorFlow only supports 64-bit Python 3.5+ on Windows (see more info [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/get_started/os_setup#pip_installation_on_windows)).

Perhaps you have Python's default installation, which comes in a 32-bit version. If that's the case, you can download the 64-bit Python 3.5 or later from [here](https://www.python.org/downloads/) to run in your Conda environment and then you should be able to install/run TensorFlow without any issues.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that the Python version installed in the Environment is 3.5 not 3.6. Since 3.6 was released Conda automatically sets that version as default for python 3. However, it is still not supported by Tensorflow.

Answer (score 0):

You can work using tensorflow library along with other essential libraries using the [Dockerfile](https://hub.docker.com/r/datmo/tensorflow/~/dockerfile/). Using Docker for environment are a good way to run experiments in reproducible manner as in this [blog](http://mathalope.co.uk/2017/08/02/how-to-setup-a-data-science-workflow-with-kaggle-python-docker-image-on-laptop/)

You can also try using [datmo](https://datmo.io/) in order setup environment and track machine learning projects for making it reproducible using datmo CLI tool.